# C++11 compiler for windows

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, c++11

I was just watching a few videos on Channel9. I found things like lambdas really cool. when I tried to copy the example, it failed. `auto` didn't work either.

I'm using Nokia's qtcreator which ships with gcc-4.4.0.

I wanted to know which compiler has the fun features implemented so I could play around and learn. I'm not anti MS or anyhting so I don't mind trying Visual Studio if it has those features.

Comment: If you just want to try C++11 features there are many online C++ compilers that support C++11: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nearly all C++11 features are implemented in the GCC 4.6.x . A good place to get latest GCC builds (MinGW) is the TDM website - http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download . It should be easy to replace your current GCC with TDM GCC by overwriting files...

Comment: Note that although these might seem nice, TDM does some nasty changes (remove command line options, change ABI) that make them incompatible with the vanilla (unpatched) upstream versions.

Comment: Yes. Note I said "a good place" - that does not necessarily mean the only one. :) I cross-compile build my own Windows GCC on GNU/Linux. ;)

Answer (score 8):

A special version of MinGW:

### MinGW-Builds gives you everything gcc offers (currently 4.7.2)

That is: **Including support for std::thread, std::async, std::future and friends.**

As far as I know that's by far the most complete C++11 you can get on Windows.

You just get the [MinGW-build binaries here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/). Unlike other gcc-based installations it supports posix threads, which are currently key to getting the gcc support for C++11 threads and friends working on Windows.

Extract the directory mingw to any location and add the following two paths to your PATH environment variable: (well, change F:\coding ...)

```
F:\coding\MinGW\bin
F:\coding\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin
```

Add both, separated by semi colon. You will need to log out or reboot. To verify that you got it right, you can open a command prompt, and write

```
g++ --version
```

You should get a response like this, mentioning MinGW-builds:

```
g++ (Built by MinGW-builds project) 4.7.2 
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc. ...
```

I wrote a more complete instruction for getting this going with Eclipse, here: http://scrupulousabstractions.tumblr.com/post/36441490955/eclipse-mingw-builds

Comment: on windows there is not thread support at all unluckily. Just try to run any std::thread example for example by installing code::blocks + mingw (GCC 4.7.1). that's the short way. Even if you install GCC+MingW you will have no thread support on windows

Comment: @DarioOO, that is not correct, and the whole point of my post. I've even tried it extensively. Both std::thread and async/future work fine with the versions and instructions I posted. + Now you get gcc 4.8 (even better) if you follow my link above.

Comment: so std::thread will work with Gcc 4.8 under windows? now i try thx

Comment: I tested MinGW-Builds toolchains (v4.8 posix and windows threads model versions). std::threads only works in posix version, not in win32 threads model. If you want full C++11 support, you should use posix toolchain.

Answer (score 5):

For playing around and learning C++11 on Windows, I recommend [MinGW Distro](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) by Stephan T. Lavavej. The newest version contains GCC 4.8.2 and Boost 1.55.0.

Answer (score 4):

Take a [look at MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) if you're looking for a gcc-compatible compiler on Windows that supports a number of C++11 features.

Also if you're just looking for lambas and auto, as well as some other C++11 features like `decltype`, etc., (again, not as many feature are implemented compared to the latest stable gcc branch) then you can also use the [free Visual Studio 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express) for C++ on Windows.

Comment: Especially the full-features Personal Builds (like sezero's 4.5 or my 4.6) offer all the fun C++11 stuff you'd want. (by full-featured I mean gdb and mingw32-make included in the package)

Comment: @rubenvb : from where can I get your builds?

Comment: nikhil: [32-bit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/) and [64-bit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/) and just click on rubenvb or a sezero version. Note I don't build multilib compilers; the 32-bit version only builds 32-bit binaries, the 64-bit version only builds 64-bit. You should be able to just replace your existing MinGW install with these. The latest version at the time of writing is 4.6.3 (prerelease) which is pretty close to the 4.6.2 release.

Comment: I got your build but it doesn't support auto.

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://www.aristeia.com/C++11/C++11FeatureAvailability.htm) for an overview of the compilers and the supported C++11 features.

Comment: I find the page linked on that page to be more helpful: https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport

Answer (score 2):

Scott Meyers maintains a webpage here:

**[C++11FeatureAvailability](http://www.aristeia.com/C++11/C++11FeatureAvailability.htm)**

The First link on the Webpage is:

**[Apache Wiki Overview of C++11 Support in Several Compilers](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport)** is what you should have a look at.It doccuments in detail C++11 features supported by all popular compilers.

Answer (score 2):

The [Visual Studio 11 preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/hh127353) also [supports lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409293%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2017 has support in C++11, C++14, & C++17. + some of the Modern C++ "experimental" modules. If you decide on Visual Studio, you set the C++ standard at the project properties. C++11 is by default, but you can set it to C++14, C++17, or latest draft.

Comment: What the heck man. This is a 7 year old question. Of course this is not an issue anymore...

Answer (score 1):

As regards g++, C++0x feature support should be detailed here: [C++0x/C++11 Support in GCC - GNU Project - Free Software Foundation (FSF)](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test most of the C++11 syntax using a Windows machine you have two options:

1. Install Cygwin and compile from sources `gcc-4.7` (latest snapshot) and `clang++` with `libstdc++`. However it is not guaranteed that this will work.
2. Safest bet: Install a modern Linux (such as Ubuntu if you are a Linux newbie) in a virtual machine (VirtualBox is a free virtual machine application) and in this virtual machine compile `gcc-4.7` and `clang++`. I was able to successfully compile both of them on Ubuntu 11.10 following the instructions from [this website](http://www.solarianprogrammer.com).
3. Best option, as of 2014, is to use Visual Studio 2013 updated with the latest CTP (this will work even for the Express edition).

Comment: Also be careful, with the virtual machine and gcc! Sometimes gcc can use all of your processor time, and render everything else dog slow, especially if your under an graphical desktop (in oposition to the console).

Also if your using ubuntu, you almost don't need to compile anything, you just need to find an deb file with the package you want, look in ubuntu forum for that.

Answer (score 0):

Few Min-GW Compilers do not support C++ Version 11 or later. This version is required for thread in OpenCV. So I will suggest using [TDM-GCC Compiler](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/) instead of MinGW Compiler. Install this compiler and set path C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin to the system's environmental variable.