# Concepts-Lite in gcc (with links to TS)

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

As highlighted by [a recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32230675/3098505) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290240/how-do-i-build-gcc-with-c-concepts-concepts-lite-support), `gcc` now supports `concepts-lite` in builds from its svn trunk.

The same question links to the <strike>most recent</strike> TS, [N4377](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4377.pdf). *Edit* - answer has a newer TS.

A helpful paper can be found labelled [N3580](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3580.pdf) - this is from 2013, and the authors are Andrew Sutton, Bjarne Stroustrup and Gabriel Dos Reis.

A list of tweaks to N4377 can be found labelled [N4434](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4434.pdf). This gives 3 suggested changes to the N4377 paper and lists as its reply point Walter E. Brown.

These papers/Technical Specifications are similar, but have various small changes in each case.

Is there some simple way to discover what `gcc` currently implements? Or indeed, plans to implement?

As a side question: Is `ConceptClang` or some similarly named project related to the c++1z concepts? A [mailing list post](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2015-May/042770.html) from May 2015 collected some thoughts, in particular that:

> Larisse may have some work done for the concepts ts, in addition to
>   her C++0x efforts.

No further reply was made to that thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's my understanding that the GCC maintainers plan to implement Concepts as specified in the final TS that is soon to be published: [N4549 C++ Extensions for Concepts](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4549.pdf). Most of that specification is implemented in GCC, with the notable exception of "generalized auto deduction" which is necessary to compile syntax like `std::pair<auto, auto> foo = std::make_pair(x, y);`. The implementation is still very rough - a quick search for [open bugs with "[concepts]" in the title has 38 hits](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?bug_status=UNCONFIRMED&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=SUSPENDED&bug_status=WAITING&bug_status=REOPENED&cf_known_to_fail_type=allwords&cf_known_to_work_type=allwords&component=c%2B%2B&list_id=128319&product=gcc&query_format=advanced&short_desc=%5Bconcepts%5D&short_desc_type=allwordssubstr), so exactly what is implemented and what works well changes from week to week.

> Is `ConceptClang` or some similarly named project related to the c++1z concepts?

`ConceptClang` is (was?) an implementation of C++0x concepts which I believe has been dead for some time now. There are a few people who have started looking at implementing the Concepts TS in clang in the last several months, they've only submitted a handful of patches to recognize the `concept` keyword and parse the syntax of `concept` function and variable declarations.